# javascript: Preload ONE image at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a rotating background that preloads the images when the page is loaded.  However,  I would like to preload the images one at a time, if that is even possible.

My code:

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
        $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){


            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        // Alternatively you could use:
        // (new Image()).src = this;
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var b = [<? $img = getContents(ROOT."/img/backgrounds/");
            foreach($img as $i)
            {   echo "\"" . $i . "\"";
                if($i != end($img)) echo ",";
            }
        ?>];
    preload(b);

    var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*b.length)
    $('#bg1').css("background-image", "url('/img/backgrounds/"+b[r]+"')");

    var alt = false;
    var delay = 50000;
    var speed = ((delay / 3)*2);
    var opacity = 1;

    setInterval(function() {
        var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*b.length);

        //put the individual preload code here

        switch(alt)
        {   case true:
                $('#bg1').css("background-image", "url('/img/backgrounds/"+b[r]+"')");
                $('#bg1').fadeTo(speed,opacity);
                $('#bg2').fadeOut(speed);
            break;
            case false:
                $('#bg2').css("background-image", "url('/img/backgrounds/"+b[r]+"')");
                $('#bg2').fadeTo(speed,opacity);
                $('#bg1').fadeOut(speed);
            break;
        }
        alt = !alt;
        }, delay);

    });
```

The code above works fine. If there is a better way please let me know! But otherwise how can I just preload one image at a time?

Comment: Why? Kinda defeats the purpose of preloading.

Comment: @Juhana If it's a rotating slideshow, the first image will be displayed for a period of time before switching to the next. The next image should be preloaded before it switches, but if you have all the upcoming images preloading simultaneously, it may interfere with the initial load. Loading sequential images sequentially allows the initial image to load much more rapidly, then load the rest invisibly in the background before the next image in the slideshow begins.

Answer (score 2):

```
function preload(arrayOfImages, index) {
    index = index || 0;

    if (arrayOfImages && arrayOfImages.length > index) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            console.log(arrayOfImages[index] + " loaded successfully");
            preload(arrayOfImages, index + 1);
        };
        img.src = arrayOfImages[index];
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzaYw/)